# Heroku go-getting-started not running localy

Tags: heroku, go

Does anyone know why i'm unable to run the go-getting-started application localy?

```
go get github.com/heroku/go-getting-started/cmd/...
cd $env:GOPATH/src/github.com/heroku/go-getting-started

PS C:\Users\XXXX\gocode\src\github.com\heroku\go-getting-started> heroku  local
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
[OKAY] Trimming display Output to 107 Columns
11:28:05 PM web.1 |  'go-getting-started' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
11:28:05 PM web.1 |  operable program or batch file.
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  null
11:28:05 PM web.1 Exited Abnormally
PS C:\Users\XXXX\gocode\src\github.com\heroku\go-getting-started> code .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-go#run-the-app-locally):

> If you see an error about an unrecognized command or “command not found”, then $GOPATH/bin is likely not in your $PATH or the trailing ... was missing from the go get github.com/heroku/go-getting-started/.... command used during “Prepare the App”.

Make sure `$GOPATH/bin` (in your case, `C:\Users\XXXX\gocode\bin`) is in your `$PATH` variable. The server binary, `go-getting-started`, is already there, you just need to make it available to the command line.